# What's the difference between "content" and "contented"?

Tags: prepositions, american-english, word-usage

What's the difference between "content" and "contented"?

> I feel **content** with my present condition.
>
> I feel **contented** with my present condition.
>
> When she calls me by my name sweetly, I feel **contented**.
>
> When she calls me by my name sweetly, I feel **content**.

Hopefully, that'd be enough examples. One with the preposition, one without.

Comment: First, it's _content **with**_ and _contented **with**_; never _of_. Second, there is really no difference between one's unspecified emotional state (_content_) and a state reached as a result of some phenomenon acting on one (_contented_).

Comment: @JohnLawler Done.

Comment: Though there is no difference between the two words one might ask why there are two variants. "content" is the Latin/French form, an adjective derived from a Latin past participle. "contented is derived from the Latin/English verb to content. So we have the same word in the Latin form and the English form.

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest that *contented* is slightly narrower in meaning than *content*. *contented* carries the suggestion that the emotion is caused by circumstances, whereas *content* does not.

The adjective *content* is complete in itself. It describes a state of being / mind. We can learn to become content with our life, even if it is not the life we would have wished for.

By contrast, the grammatical structure of *I am contented* suggests that it might be the passive form of *X contents me*, which implies that some unspecified thing is causing that feeling. One might feel contented by the embrace of a loved one.

Answer (score 3):

My (AusE) intuition is that the "contented" has a warmer, fuzzier feeling associated with it. I'd guess that comes from its use in literature ("They lay down, contentedly in front of the fire."), whereas the shorter form is commonly used in modern newspapers ("The union said they were content with the current arrangement.")

So, I would say "contented" has more of an emotional effect  ("pleasantly happy"), while "content" is more neutral ("satisfied"). I have nothing to back this up with. :)

Comment: Cool. It seems you've cited a newspaper or literature. Can you specify the actual book or newspaper issue?

Comment: Is that a requirement of answers? I'm new here.

Comment: I don't know either. I'm only asking, because having the actual source ensures that the person is not making stuff up. :)

Comment: @SteveBennett. It's A Very Good Idea. Highly Recommended.